# ResourceWriter data formatting

Tags: edit, resx

I have a `.resx` file to update some data. I can read the data from the file via a `ResXResourceSet` object, but when I want to save the data back, the saved data format is
unrecognizable. How do I edit `.resx` files? Thanks.

```
  ResXResourceSet st = new ResXResourceSet(@"thepath");
  entries=new List<DictionaryEntry>();    
  DictionaryEntry curEntry ;

  foreach (DictionaryEntry ent in st)
  {

      if (ent.Key.ToString() == "Page.Title")
      {
          curEntry = ent;
          curEntry.Value = "change this one"
          entries.Add(curEntry);
      }
      else
      {
          entries.Add(ent);  
      }       
  }

  st.Close();
  System.Resources.ResourceWriter wr = new ResourceWriter(@"thepath");

  foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in entries)
  {
      wr.AddResource(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
  }

  wr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi again i searched up and found that..

ResourceWriter writes data as binary type
ResourceReader reads data as binary type

ResXResourceWriter  writes data as xml format
ResXResourceReader  reads data as xml format

so example on top using ResXResourceWriter,ResXResourceReader  instead of  ResourceReader ,ResourceWriter will manipulate resources as xml type

Comment: Not sure ResXResourceWriter exists anymore as of .NET 3.5

Comment: why not? http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter(v=VS.100).aspx